# Xcode 6.1: Loading a plug-in failed

Tags: xcode, macos

I updated Xcode from AppStore but I couldn't open it due to this error message: 
**"Loading a plug-in failed 

The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled"** 
I tried uninstalling Xcode by deleting it from Application folder and reinstall it but the problem is still the same.
Can anyone figure out what's wrong, and how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Did you by any chance update your Python? Anyway, I did and I think I also removed python 2.7 for some reason. Turns out, Xcode uses python 2.7 and is required for Xcode 6.0 onwards.

Simply download [python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8/), install it and all should be good.

Comment: Thanks you sir, you saved my life! I've removed python 2.7 and install python 3.4, and my Xcode breaks, after re-installing python 2.7, My Xcode came alive!

Comment: @Johnny I know the feeling, I reinstalled Xcode twice before I learned it was my removal of Python 2.7 that was the problem. Glad it helped you.

Comment: You save me from hell :)

Comment: OMG This fixed everything! I installed python 3.5 and removed all older versions and lined everything to the newer version. It broke home-brew, git, Xcode, sublime text!

Comment: this is a vague explanation. can someone tell me where to find the log for Xcode? I reinstalled python, still having this problem...How are you people getting Xcode fixed?

Answer (score 6):

I have run into the exact same issue with XCode 6.3 and `brew upgrade python` to version 2.7.10.

For whatever reason the symlinks at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` were not updated...

The fix:

```
sudo rm -f /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
sudo rm -f /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

(obviously your paths/versions might differ)

And then XCode starts working again.

Comment: Try "sudo rm: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7" firstly, then output shows " No such file or directory". What I do, is copy the Python.framework from /usr/local/Cellar, then did the above steps. It works for me. Thank you.

Comment: I've changed to `rm -f` so that there are no errors displayed.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem had to do with a missing iTunes.app. I had previously deleted iTunes, but it turns out that Xcode 9 (and possibly Xcode 8) needs the iTunes.app, and will fail with the mysterious "Loading a plug-in failed" error if iTunes is missing on your system.

Downloading and installing iTunes from https://www.apple.com/ca/itunes/download/ solved the issue for me.

By the way, you may be able to get more info about what's causing the plug-in error by running `xcodebuild` on the command line.