# Xcode 8 doesn't Start: Loading a plug-in failed

Tags: python, ios, xcode, xcode8

I have a big problem with Xcode 8, can not get it to start ^ _ ^, I always get the following error:

> Loading a plug-in failed.
>
> The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or
>   damaged and may need to be reinstalled.

I am looking at the logs I could see that the problem is Python, so I tried to update Python, reinstall but nothing very wrong T_T

> [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in
>   com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB
>   (/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin),
>   error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587
>   "dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C480000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python: mmap()
>   error 1 at address=0x11C6C0000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT in
>   Segment::map() mapping
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C900000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing
>   necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling
>   the bundle.,
>   NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB,
>   NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C480000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python: mmap()
>   error 1 at address=0x11C6C0000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT in
>   Segment::map() mapping
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C900000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python,
>   NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DebuggerLLDB” couldn’t be loaded
>   because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}, dyldError =
>   dlopen(/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB,
>   0): Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11CB40000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python: mmap()
>   error 1 at address=0x11CD80000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT in
>   Segment::map() mapping
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11CFC0000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   2016-06-15 02:05:24.324 Xcode[64100:586329] [MT] DVTAssertions:
>   Warning in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-11160.22/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:262
>   Details:  Xcode failed its initial plug-in scan, error = Error
>   Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed."
>   UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB,
>   DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite
>   plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.,
>   DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB,
>   0): Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11CB40000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python: mmap()
>   error 1 at address=0x11CD80000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT in
>   Segment::map() mapping
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11CFC0000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed.,
>   NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB”
>   at path
>   “/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin”
>   could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins
>   may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f97fcc92500 {Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587
>   "dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C480000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python: mmap()
>   error 1 at address=0x11C6C0000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT in
>   Segment::map() mapping
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C900000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing
>   necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling
>   the bundle.,
>   NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB,
>   NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C480000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python: mmap()
>   error 1 at address=0x11C6C0000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT in
>   Segment::map() mapping
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x11C900000, size=0x00171000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python,
>   NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode8b.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DebuggerLLDB” couldn’t be loaded
>   because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}}} Function:
>   BOOL _IDEInitializePlugInManager(IDEInitializationOptions, NSError
>   *__autoreleasing *) Thread:   {number = 1, name = main} Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this
>   warning message and any useful information you can provide.

currently in my car I installed 2.7.11 Python and Python 3.5, but the default version is the 2.7.11.

The path in which the two Python are installed is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

Comment: Have you tried just re-downloading Xcode 8?

Comment: yes but not work 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.1: Loading a plug-in failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064802/xcode-6-1-loading-a-plug-in-failed)

Comment: How to get that log? I am new to Mac. I'm getting the same error but don't know the reason. I'm trying to install Xcode_8.2.1.xip

Comment: hi, open your terminal and execute this command: open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode . this command show your console log for the application

Comment: You do not need to (and you shouldn't) add "solved" in a question title. Instead you can mark one of the answers as the accepted one by tapping on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

just for the record, Apple says the problem is related to the fact that I updated Python (although I downloaded from the official website python.org) and indicates that 8 of Xcode is more control for the XcodeGhost problem.

I have to try to reinsert the 2.7.10 version and see if this works for me.

Comment: You changed the system-version of `python`?

Comment: Don't ever do that.  You can add alternatives in `/usr/local` and `/opt/local`.

Comment: I solved it by restoring an official version of Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin

Comment: the interesting thing is that the official python.org not good, so I had to withdraw from the version of the operating system packages

Answer (score 2):

If facing the

`Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice`

Try the solution given at this link

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3863980?start=0&tstart=0

Just double click `Xcode 4.3.1 dmg` file ...

Then window will show Xcode app.

Right Cick App

Show Package contents

Then go to `/Contents/Resources/Packages/`

Install That MobileDevice.pkg ...

After installation

Double click on Xcode app ...

Just See Xcode is ready ...

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem,
I ran

```
    xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I also have the problem, and I copy an official version of Python 2.7 to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`, the problem is gone.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I had already solved by installing an Apple compatible version of Python

Comment: which version is that? I have python 2.7.13, I have the same problem. xCode giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete(copy them on other folder for backup) everything in this folder:

`~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I had already solved by installing an Apple compatible version of Python

Comment: I don't even have that folder