# Xcode 8: Loading a plug-in failed

Tags: python, ios, xcode

when launching Xcode beta 8 on a macOS Sierra beta I'm getting this error:

> Loading a plug-in failed.
>   The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.

After searching, it seems that the issue is related with python and the new security measures that Apple introduced after XCode Ghost.

I couldn't find a solution, anybody can help?

**EDIT**
By looking at the Xcode logs, I noticed that it has NOTHING (apparently) to do with Python.
I see a whole bunch of
*Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.**
errors

I have to say that I also have Xcode 7 installed on my machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 don't Start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824143/xcode-8-dont-start)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact thing happen to me except on High Sierra. I had deleted the old version folders of Python in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`, which was a mistake seeing that these are the Apple installed Python files. After trying to launch Xcode, Xcode could no longer access the Python files it needed. Unfortunately I had deleted them and emptied the trash, so the only way I could restore those files was by reinstalling High Sierra.

So if you run into this plugin error and you've messed with Python files, you need to recover those files either by taking them back out of the trash or by reinstalling your operating system (reinstalling doesn't erase the data on your computer, but it will add missing files, such as the Python ones I deleted).

Hope that helps someone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the similar logs that seemed to have nothing to do with Python, but what ended up working for it is removing python from `/Library/Frameworks` with help from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/3046504

It was still not working, but then extracting Xcode 9.1 from the `xip` and launching it triggered some additional installer all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, found the solution over there : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/100026

> I found the key to a solution here:
> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/100026
>
> In the Xcode app directory:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages
>
> there are four packages: CoreTypes.pkg MobileDevice.pkg
> MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg XcodeSystemResources.pkg
>
> I had to open and install all of these packages to fix the Xcode
> launch failure. Then Xcode opens normally.

Answer (score -1):

if you were doing something in Python, you may have accidently deleted some files. I had the same problem and I was trying to fix it for a few days. Finally, I found a way how to fix it. Just right click on **"Finder app"** icon and select **"Go to folder.."**, then paste **"/System/Library/Frameworks/"**. If you have there a file called **"Python.framework"**, just **delete it** and **download new one** on my website[[link]](https://abrahamdominik.eu/sFiles/Python.framework.zip). Then just restart your Mac. If it works, contact me so I know if it worked. If not, conctact me too so we can figure it out together

Comment: Note to others: *do not* replace system files with something you've downloaded from some random stranger's web site.